# Doctrine: связь в аннотациях: для каждой выбранной "компании" автоматически идет еще по одному запросу к базе

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2

У меня есть две сущности со связью один-к-одному, описанной в аннотациях (компании и их субдомены)

В документации есть [пример](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/doctrine.html#fetching-related-objects):

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
    ->find($id);

$categoryName = $product->getCategory()->getName();
```

И сказано:

> When you call $product->getCategory()->getName(), Doctrine silently
>   makes a second query to find the Category that's related to this
>   Product.
>
> What's important is the fact that you have easy access to the
>   product's related category, but the category data isn't actually
>   retrieved until you ask for the category (i.e. it's "lazily loaded").

Если использовать стандартное `find`, то все так.
Если написать свой query (без `inner join` и без вызова а-ля `$product->getCategory()`, в моем случае это `$company->getSubdomain()`), то к базе сразу идет еще один, тот самый ленивый запрос.

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(array('c'))
    ->from('TestBundle:Company', 'c')
    ->andWhere('c.city = :cityId')
    ->setParameter('cityId', $cityId);
```

Если выборка, допустим, на 5 компаний, то идет еще ПЯТЬ запросов к базе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно 30 компаний на страницу.

Что я делаю не так? Как отключить эти запросы пока я явно их не запрошу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Это давно известное поведение, [ответ по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362901/doctrine2-one-to-one-relation-auto-loads-on-query).
>
> Решение: оставить связь только со [стороны владельца](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) - это
>   сущность, которая имеет связь. Или изменить владельца.